# linq2db select and automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, linq2db

I have code like this

```
            return dbConnection.SomeLogTable
                .OrderByDescending(logRecord=> logRecord.Timestamp)
                .Select(dto => _mapper.Map<JournalRecord>(dto))
                .Skip(offset)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToList();
```

I wonder how this code manages to produce correct SQL query without full table fetch. It obviously can't translate select into SQL as it uses AutoMapper method, so how it works?

UPD. Query 10 items that linq2db logs show:

```
DECLARE @take Integer -- Int32
SET     @take = 10
DECLARE @skip Integer -- Int32
SET     @skip = 0

SELECT
        *all fields listed
FROM
        someLogTable dto
ORDER BY
        dto."timestamp" DESC
LIMIT :take OFFSET :skip
```

Comment: I wonder if you perhaps want to use the [Queryable extensions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)?

Comment: Some c# function are mapped as sql convertible, and some are not.
PS. You have to be carefull, if you will use something that isnt convertible to sql, it will stop generating sql at that instruction and will run the query, then every row (probably lots of them, based on where you used not convertible C# function) will be fetched with C# specific fuctions.

Comment: It doesn't, Linq2Sql translates as much as it can, but if it can't it (well, Entity Framework) silently switches to *client side evaluation*. In your case, I'd highly suggest you do the `Skip(offset).Takge(pageSize)` part *before* calling `Select`

Comment: best to use the sql profiler and check the generated sql query https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: As suggested use Automapper's [ProjectTo](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html)

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik, how to undestand what is convertable and what's not?

Comment: @MindSwipe It's linq2db, not ef or linq2sql. And its logs show that query is perfect.

Comment: @SkySurfer, if you use `.Select(dto => _mapper.Map<JournalRecord>(dto))`, `linq2db` will retrieve ALL fields from table. With `ProjectTo` it will retrieve ONLY needed for DTO class itself. I'm one of `linq2db` creators and I know what it can and what is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be carefull in that case, some c# function are mapped as sql convertible and some are not, and that may have huge impact on performance when you use it in wrong order.

For instance: If an used function is not covertible and you use it earlier than other convertible function, it will take more rows than u expect.

According to your question: how to undestand what is convertable and what's not?

It has to implement `**IQueryable**' interface.

If you are not sure, you can always right click it in Visual Studio -> Go To Definition, and you will notice that for example: Where and Union are **sql convertible** functions, because they implement `**IQueryable**' interface.

[image: IQueryable extensions]

Comment: Well, the question is I can put any code into IQuerable Select or Where method, how it works this around. In my example I put autoMapper.Map into select, this code cant be transled into SQL but linq2db somehow managed to generate correct query